# Django Login Form Input Fields not showing up

Tags: python, django, django-forms

working on a Django Web project for a class.

Created an own template for the login page, that looks like this

```
{% extends 'thirdauth/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Login</h2>
<div class="login-form">
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'thirdauth:login' %}">
      {{form.as_p}}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
      <p><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
  </form>
</div>
<br>
<p><strong>-- OR --</strong></p>
<a href="{% url 'thirdauth:social:begin' 'github' %}">Login with GitHub</a><br>
{% endblock %}
```

The only problem that I face is that the input fields for user and password + labels are not showing up when the sites initially loads. When I click on the Login button, the fields appear and I can enter everything and it works fine...

Here is the urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
            url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
            url(r'^auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
            url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
            url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.authentication, name='authentication'),
]
```

I'm thankful for help, I think it is just a small stupid mistake from me, but I'm not able to find it, most help on the internet focuses on self defined forms.

**EDIT**
views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template.context import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def authentication(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html')
```

**EDIT 2**
second views.py:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import *
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import wikipediaapi

def home(request):
  return render(request, 'worldmap/home.html',
             {'worldmap': home})

def denverText (request):
    wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')
    page_py = wiki_wiki.page('Denver')
    return page_py.summary[0:60];

@login_required
def plannerGetStarted (request):
    return render(request, 'worldmap/planner.html')
```

[image: Snapshot Login]

**SOLVED:**
added this code to my views.py:

```
def authentication(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        user = authenticate(username=cd['username'],
                    password=cd['password'])
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                #return HttpResponse('Authenticated ' \
                 #       'successfully')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Disabled account')

    else:
        return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
else:
    form = LoginForm()

return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Please show us the `views.py` that renders the `form`

Comment: I followed the approach from the book "Django By Example", Chapter 4. They say you use in built views from Django and don't mention that one has to change the own views.py, so I ahven't touched that file. I added the content of my views.py

Comment: Well your view does not create a form. How should the template be able to render it? I suspect that the form action takes you to a different view that actually creates a form.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought that would be the point in using the django authentication, so I don't have to code it myself.

In the whole project is only this other views.py (see Edit 2), but there is also no render function of the form.

I can provide some screenshots, after clicking the login/submit button the form fields appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is what i think is happening here. If i'm right in saying that you are navigating to /accounts/login first.

When you go to /accounts/login django uses your authentication view which just renders the html without creating a form. This is why you don't see the fields initially.

The form is setup to submit to /login/ because action is set to "{% url 'thirdauth:login' %}". /login/ is using the default django login view. So once you sumbit the form with no fields this causes an error in the defualt view which redirects you back to /login/.  This is why you then see the fields with the "this field is required" errors after clicking submit.

Hope that explains it

Comment: thanks for the explanation of the logic, I couldn't figure that out! I added the code (see post) to my views.py and now it works.