# DJANGO Login // INPUT FIELDS not working // Error messages not showing

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-forms, cloud9

****** **Hear me out, I know this is kinda long and I *hate* to sound like this, but I haven't slept in 4 days and this is part of my project due for school so I would really appreciate literally *any* input on this** ******

Hello, I'm relatively new to Django but nonetheless, I've been bouncing from tutorial to tutorial on youtube and Django documentation try to make up for that. I've created the polls application, and was also creating several other applications but both times when I was almost complete, they went **COMPLETELY** blank white and I had to START *ALL* OVER. At this point, I'm just about *tired* of Django, but I'm willing to continue because I really *hate* quitting.

Anyways that's not what this question is about (although if you could help get my apps up and running again that would be great! I'll put a link down below).

After my most recent app crash after trying to learn how to do a login page. I started yet another app called accounts which would be SOLELY dedicated to login/logout/register. However, so far things haven't been working out great.

I started out following one tutorial on youtube, but then there was a whole bunch of errors that I couldn't get out of that had to deal with indentations and stuff. So I started my app over with another tutorial, which is this one right here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIgVhBBm6zI

I tried looking past my errors (which was the fact that my input fields weren't showing up) for this video and tried to move on to the next one which was the logic behind the login page. However I know had ANOTHER ERROR. Now the error messages weren't working and whenever I click submit, nothing happens. The page just *BASICALLY* refreshes. And I know that I haven't got deep enough to the registration part, which would allow me to actually log in, but I'm expecting some sort of error message to tell me that I don't have an account or something.

For my input fields, I've tried several things (including this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49165201/django-login-form-input-fields-not-showing-up)) and nothing works. The only thing that remotely comes close is either me putting in the fields manually in Html (which I know I shouldn't do) or linking the form.html to a form template which just checks if the user puts something in the fields or not (which also doesn't work).

Here is what my code looks like, and if you're still reading this thank you so much for bearing with me thus far. (Also note the commented out sections are things that I have tried out before)

views.py

```
    from django.contrib.auth import (
    authenticate,
    get_user_model,
    login,
    logout,

    )
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import UserLoginForm

# Create your views here.
def login_view(request):
    title = "Login"
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')

    return render(request, "accounts/form.html", {"form":form, "title": title})


# def authentication(request):
#     if request.method == 'POST':
#         title = "Login"
#         form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
#         if form.is_valid():
#             cd = form.cleaned_data
#             user = authenticate(username=cd['username'],
#                         password=cd['password'])
#             if user is not None:
#                 if user.is_active:
#                     login(request, user)
#                     #return HttpResponse('Authenticated ' \
#                      #       'successfully')
#                     return HttpResponseRedirect('accounts/home.html/')
#             else:
#                 return HttpResponse('Disabled account')

#         else:
#             return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
#     else:
#         form = UserLoginForm()

#     return render(request, 'accounts/form.html', {'form': form})



def register_view(request):
    return render(request,"accounts/form.html",{})

def logout_view(request):
    return render(request,"accounts/form.html",{})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import (
    authenticate,
    get_user_model,
    login,
    logout,

    )

User = get_user_model()

class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput) 

    class Meta: 
        model = User 
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

    def clean(self,*args,**kwargs):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if not user:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This user does not exist")
        if not user.check_password(password):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect Password")
        if not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This user is no longer active.")
        return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args,**kwargs)
```

form.html

```
{% extends 'accounts/base.html' %}


{% block main_content %}

    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">{{ title }}</h2>
        <form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data' class="form-signin">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <!--{% include 'accounts/form-template.html' %}-->
                <h2 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h2>

                <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                <input type="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
                <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="{{ title }}">Sign In</button>
            </form>

    </div>


    <!--<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>-->
    <!--    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>-->
    <!--    <form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}-->
    <!--        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='{{ title }}' />-->
    <!--    </form>-->
    <!--</div>-->

{% endblock %}
```

form-template.html

```
{% for field in form %}

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">{{ field }}</div>
</div>
```

{% endfor %}

base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Accounts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'accounts/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'accounts/signin.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'accounts/style.css' %}" />
</head>

<body>


    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">

            {% block main_content %} 
            {% endblock %} 
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

settings.py (small preview of the important bits)

```
    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'accounts',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',]
```

urls.py (for my site not app)

```
    from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from accounts.views import (login_view, register_view, logout_view)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/', login_view, name='login'),
    # url(r'^login/', authentication, name='authentication'),
]
```

images of my site:

[This what it looks like with the StackOverflow fix from the post I was talking about (yes that's it and the white square is actually button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIKKg.jpg)

[This is me manually putting in the fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyBz7.jpg)

[This is when I include the form template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxzPV.jpg)

As shown everything is just off and I don't want to have to restart again because there's simply not enough time and I'm going to fail the class.

***Updated* base**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Accounts</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'accounts/signin.css' %}" />
</head>

<body>


    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">

            {% block main_content %} 
            {% endblock %} 
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[***New webpage***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54J4L.jpg)

Comment: Is the built-in login view not adequate for your purposes? And if you are referring to the overlap of fields on the label, that is a css issue. your labels have a fixed width which is not enough for them

Comment: From the code you've shown, the page would just refresh. Your form's clean method calls authenticate and does nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Ramkishore, but how would I know if the Django form doesn't suit me?

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, but I've tried everything from refreshing to restarting my server several times but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I got the default login form to show (add `{{form.as_p}}` )

form.html

```
{% extends 'accounts/base.html' %}
{% block main_content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='{{ title }}' />
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Also in base.html, included complete bootstrap+jquery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

Then in views.py

```
def login_view(request):
    title = "Login"
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)      
        if user is not None:
          login(request, user)
          # or any other success page
          return HttpResponse("Logged in")
    return render(request, "accounts/form.html", {"form":form, "title": title})
```

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!! Thanks a lot Shivam! I really appreciate it. I don't want to sound too needy or anything but when I took your suggestion about the bootstrap and jquery in base template, it didn't really work. Yes I can see some instances of the jumbotron template, but I'm trying to make it look like [this sign in page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/)

Comment: At the bottom of my question I updated what my page and my base template looks like now.

Comment: Updated the answer, use `form.as_p` in template.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are rendering the template even if the form is submitted. Try this:

```
 def login_view(request):
        title = "Login"
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)      
            if user is not None:
              login(request, user)
              # Redirect to a success page.


        return render(request, "accounts/form.html", {"form":form, "title": title})
```

Change your form.html inputs to this:

```
<input name="username" type="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
<input name="password" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
```

Also in your UserLoginForm change fields to this, if not valid() would fail:

```
fields = ("username", "password")
```

Here is a helpful [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate)

Comment: I appreciate your feedback Dasith, but I tried it and I got back an answer saying that you used the variable 'user' before it was assigned since you assigned it in the first if statement.  The error says:
                                                                                
UnboundLocalError at /login/
local variable 'user' referenced before assignment

Comment: @X-TremeFighter12, insert `user = None` above the `form.is_valid()` block and you'll be able to test against whether it's `None` safely then. But what that does tell you is that your form isn't validating. Probably because that bit runs whether this is an initial request (using GET) or its a form submission to check (using POST).

Comment: @X-TremeFighter12 I made a change to the code. This should work. make sure put your logic where it says "#Redirect"

Comment: Benjamin, Dasith, I really appreciate you guys' help but I'm still having trouble getting the input fields to show since the input fields that I manually put aren't linked to anything in my database. they are basically just there for show and they wouldn't be accurate in testing if your suggestions work or not. I'm only relying on errors to tell me if something is wrong. I don't know how to show them or link them if I put them in manually in my Html.

Comment: I'm sorry for the bother but do you guys know of any ways I could show the fields from my database directly on the form in my Html? Or any way I could link them FROM my Html? any links would help, I would sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: @X-TremeFighter12 made a couple more changes. Add a print(form.errors) after "form=...", to see what the errors are, this will help you debug.